# Difficulty Displaying Two Separate Images in Three.js Portals

Tags: javascript, image, three.js

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using Three.js to create portals displaying different images. I'm encountering difficulty displaying two separate images in two different portals. One image is located at `src/App/Assets/HighTop.jpeg` for portal one, and the other image is at `src/App/Assets/FRB.jpeg` for portal two.

I've tried using `THREE.TextureLoader()` to load textures asynchronously, but I'm still unable to display both images correctly.

Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

```js
// ModalContentProvider.js

import * as THREE from 'three';

export default class ModalContentProvider {
    constructor() {
        // Define modal content
        this.modalContents = {
            portalOne: {
                imageUrl: '/App/Assets/HighTop.jpeg'
            },
            portalTwo: {
                imageUrl: '/App/Assets/FRB.jpeg'
            }
        };
    }

    async createMeshForPortal(imageUrl) {
        const texture = await this.loadTexture(imageUrl);

        // Create a plane geometry
        const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(/* dimensions */);

        // Use the texture on a material
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });

        // Create and return the mesh
        return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    }

    loadTexture(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            textureLoader.load(
                url,
                resolve, // Success callback
                undefined, // Progress callback
                reject // Error callback
            );
        });
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm attempting to use it:

```js
// Wherever you're setting up your scene

import ModalContentProvider from './ModalContentProvider.js';

const modalContentProvider = new ModalContentProvider();

// Create mesh for portal one
modalContentProvider.createMeshForPortal('/App/Assets/HighTop.jpeg')
    .then(mesh => {
        // Add mesh to the scene or manipulate it as needed
        scene.add(mesh);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error loading texture for portal one:', error);
    });

// Create mesh for portal two
modalContentProvider.createMeshForPortal('/App/Assets/FRB.jpeg')
    .then(mesh => {
        // Add mesh to the scene or manipulate it as needed
        scene.add(mesh);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error loading texture for portal two:', error);
    });
```

Despite my efforts, I'm unable to display both images in the different portals. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm using the `THREE.TextureLoader()` or how I'm structuring my code.

Any insights or suggestions on how to correctly display both images in separate portals using Three.js would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?